# What does 'CSR' mean in the context of 'CSR Racing'?

Tags: terminology, csr-racing-2

I've been playing this game (CSR2 racing) for a while but I've yet to find out what the CSR in the name comes from.

What does it mean?

Comment: If the "R" in CSR racing stands for "racing," does that mean that the game's complete name is "Custom Street Racing Racing"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom street racing! That's the name of the game!

Comment: This appears to be correct at least according to [the wiki](http://csrracing.wikia.com/wiki/CSR2): *"CSR, short for "Custom Street Racing", was initially an illegal street racing organization that was made legal some time before the events of CSR Racing..."*

Answer (score -4):

From what I can find, it appears to stand for Cincinnati Street Racing, I don't play the game so I'm not 100%, but Cincinnati has a decent sized street racing scene, so it seems to fit.